# Product view page: Error on Display Product Images per Selected color

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, product-images, product-view

Beginner on Magento 2, i'm creating a Product view Page, and i'm having **Problems** to **DISPLAY** the Product Images, i just want to Display the images of the **SELECTED** **COLOR**, but it **ONLY SHOWS** the **Configurable** Product Images.

[[image: image 11]

**When i click in the color options, nothing happens.**

[image: image2]

> Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/**gallery.phtml**

```
<?php

/**
 * Product media data template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery
 */
?>

<?php

    $images = $block->getGalleryImages()->getItems();
    foreach($images as $key => $image){

        $mainImage = current(array_filter($images, function ($img) use ($block) {
            return $block->isMainImage($img);
        }));

        $helper = $block->getData('imageHelper');
        $mainImageData = $mainImage ?
            $helper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image'):
            $mainImage->getData('medium_image_url');

        ?>

        <div class="gallery-placeholder _block-content-loading" data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder">
            <img
                alt="main product photo"
                class="gallery-placeholder__image"
                src="<?= /* @noEscape */ $image->getUrl() ?>"
            />
        </div>
      
    <?php  } ?>
```

Comment: Hi you have to check any extension installed which override core swatch-render.js file or debug core swatch-render.js file

Comment: Actually, it works when i use the Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml in default mode, but it only show in slider(one image per time), i want to show all the images per selected color.

Comment: By default magento 2 does not provide whay you want but for that you have to dig into your theme else find any free extension for gallery images